# undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3tbb8internal12NFS_AllocateEmmPv'

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, g++, undefined-reference

I am trying to run multistreaming in **ubuntu** using OpenCV. I tried to compile like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 MultiCamera.cpp -o MultiCamera `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -lz -lrt -lm -lpthread
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccylvz8g.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3tbb8internal12NFS_AllocateEmmPv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched this on **SO** before asking and most of the answers just pointed to linking the libraries properly in project settings and I have done that as one can see in the code above but the error still persists.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ c++filt _ZN3tbb8internal12NFS_AllocateEmmPv
tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*)
```

Your program has an undefined reference to 
function `tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*)`.
This function is defined in the [Intel TBB library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-tbb)
but you are not linking that library.

The linker diagnostics you have posted point out the shared library that you
have omitted to link:

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

`DSO` = *Dynamic Shared Object*. Link it by adding `-ltbb` to your linkage options.

Comment: It worked. **g++ -std=c++11 MultiCamera.cpp -o MultiCamera `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -lpthread -ltbb** Thanks!